# Map rotation event actions not working on Cesium

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cesiumjs

I am using Cesium `v1.93.0` along with Resium `v1.14.3` on React 16.8. I want to include basic action of middle click or ctrl + left click functionality for map rotation on 2D Maps.
I am currently using my Viewer as follows:

```
<Viewer style={{height: "80vh"}} timeline={false} geocoder={false} 
vrButton={false} animation={false} scene3DOnly={false} sceneModePicker={false}
ref={e => { this.viewer = e ? e.cesiumElement : null; }} 
fullscreenButton={false} sceneMode={SceneMode.SCENE2D}}>
{/* Some Body Content */}
</Viewer>
```

Here, no action for map rotation is being triggered

I have referred this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/35858166 and tried to migrate the same functionality from Cesium to Resium, but i am failing on that.

I have also referred storybook examples by resium but there also no example of map rotation is given.

I would greatly appreciate if you can provide a guide to implement 2D map rotation using Resium in ReactJs.